# How to find the largest connected region using scipy.ndimage?

Tags: image-processing, scipy, ndimage

I have a binary image. The binary image has some isolate regions like noise. I know that the expected region much larger than these isolate regions. Hence, I used the connected components to remove the isolate regions by finding the largest connected region. I have to use scipy package. I found it has some functions to do it. However, I still am in far away the result. How can I use the functions to obtain a binary image that can ignore the isolated region? Thanks

```
from scipy import ndimage
label_im, nb_labels = ndimage.label(binary_img)

# Find the largest connected component
sizes = ndimage.sum(binary_img, label_im, range(nb_labels + 1))
mask_size = sizes < 1000
remove_pixel = mask_size[label_im]
label_im[remove_pixel] = 0
labels = np.unique(label_im)
binary_img= np.searchsorted(labels, label_im)
#Select the biggest connected component
binary_img[binary_img < binary_img.max()]=0
binary_img[binary_img >= binary_img.max()]=1
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a good start, using `ndimage.sum` to find the sizes of each labeled region.

From there, you can use `sizes` (or something derived from it) as a lookup table:

```
from scipy import ndimage
label_im, nb_labels = ndimage.label(binary_img)
sizes = ndimage.sum(binary_img, label_im, range(nb_labels + 1))
mask = sizes > 1000
binary_img = mask[label_im]
```

This creates a lookup table `mask` that is `true` for the indices that correspond to the labels for the larger regions, and `false` elsewhere. Indexing into the lookup table using the labeled image yields the desired binary image.

Note that `sizes[label_im]` is an image where each region is painted with its size. That is, every pixel in region #1 gets the value of the size of region #1. You can threshold this image to remove small regions:

```
size_img = sizes[label_im]
binary_img = size_img > 1000
```

(These two lines are equivalent to the last two lines of the previous code snippet.)

Comment: I want to find a single region that has biggest connected component. So, how about the solution `mask =max(sizes)`? Because I do not know the value `1000`. Some images, the isolate regions may have size more than 1000

Comment: @Jame: That would be `mask = sizes == max(sizes)` or something similar, which is `true` only for the elements that are as big as the biggest element. This could be multiple objects, if they are exactly the same size.